# Заголовок DATE в отправке письма php

Tags: php, header, sendmail, gmail

Доброго времени! Такая проблема - отправляю письма скриптом на почту через mail php но вот gmail перестал получать письма от скрипта тогда как при указывании адресата mail.ru все приходит отлично, выяснилось что gmail блокирует письма из-за недостатка заголовков, скрипт такой

```
 $mailto = "XXXXXXXXX@list.ru";

$mailfrom = 'robot@XXXXXX.XX';

$mailbcc = "XXXXXXXXX@list.ru";

$subject = 'Заявка с сайта ';
$message = "На сайте была заполненна форма 'Оставьте заявку'\n\n Имя: ".$name." \n\n 
 Телефон: ".$phon."\n\n Кто: ".$who;


$eol = "\n";
$boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));
$header  = 'From: '.$mailfrom.$eol;
$header .= 'Reply-To: '.$mailfrom.$eol;

$header .= 'Bcc: '.$mailbcc.$eol;
$header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol;
$header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$boundary.'"'.$eol;
$header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP v'.phpversion().$eol;

$body  = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'.$eol.$eol;
$body .= '--'.$boundary.$eol;
$body .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'.$eol;
$body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'.$eol;
$body .= $eol.stripslashes($message).$eol;

$body .= '--'.$boundary.'--'.$eol;

  $sendto = mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $header);
```

В скрипт надо в заголовки письма добавить заголовок Date но я ни как не пойму как правильно его добавить, и так не получается и так, подскажите пожалуйста как добавить его правильно, а еще может каких важных заголовков в моем скрипте не хватает??

Comment: Не смотрели в сторону библиотек для отправки писем? Там все "из коробки" работает и с заголовками все в порядке. PHPMailer к примеру. Код, в вашем случае, будет значительно короче и прозрачнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить почтовый заголовок `Date` в письмо можно добавив строку вида

```
Date: Sat, 30 Jul 2016 22:38:23 +0300
```

в переменную `$header`, для этого удобно воспользоваться предопределенным классом `DateTime`, в котором уже определен формат времени RFC2822, необходимый для почтовых заголовков:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$header .= 'Date: '.$date->format(DateTime::RFC2822).$eol;
```